# Unable to connect as externally identified user using python3 and cx_Oracle on Linux

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I'm trying to write a simple python script, that will connect to my oracle database as an externally identified user, then do some stuff.  I can't get past the connection though.

If I hard code the user/password in the connection string, then it connects just fine and prints out the DB version as expected, so the format of the connect string must be valid

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('<user>','<password>','<service name>')
print (con.version)
con.close()
```

Now the os user is externally identified, as shown here:

```
sqlplus /

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Mon Sep 24 14:28:01 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage 
Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

So from what I have seen when searching, I should be able to run this code to connect:

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('','','<service name>')
print (con.version)
con.close()
```

But this gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    con = cx_Oracle.connect('','','<service name>')
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Can anyone help me out here, this feels like it should be simple!

Thanks

Comment: Are you running your python script on your database server?

Comment: Yes, it is running on the server, the same server where I can connect using 'sqlplus /'

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying works for me:

```
import cx_Oracle

connection = cx_Oracle.Connection('', '', 'my183')
cur = connection.cursor()

sql = "select user from dual"
for i in cur.execute(sql):
    print(i)
```

Produces:

```
$ python t.py
('CJ',)
```

In this instance I have a sqlnet.ora with the following (you will want to review the settings and use appropriate ones for your version and environment):

```
WALLET_LOCATION =
   (SOURCE =
     (METHOD = FILE)
     (METHOD_DATA =
       (DIRECTORY = /Users/cjones/test)
     )
   )

SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE
```

and a tnsnames.ora with:

```
my183 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orclpdb)
    )
  )
```

And my cwallet.sso was created for 'my183' (for user CJ) and is located in the same directory as tnsnames.ora & sqlnet.ora.  My TNS_ADMIN environment variable is set to that directory.

Comment: Chris, I don't have any WALLET related info in my sqlnet.ora, is this a pre-requisite for this to work?

Comment: FWIW, I am able to connect in a perl script using this syntax:

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:" , "/") or die $!;

Comment: Chris, is your CJ user externally authenticated, or is it a standard database account, with a password stored in the wallet?

Answer (score 1):

Solved!
Thanks to Bobby for pointing me in the right direction, the issue was that by specifying the DB in the connection string, it was being interpreted as a remote connection, hence was not allowed due to remote auth being disabled.

The trick was to not set the DB at all in the connection string, as illustrated below, it then worked like a charm connecting to the local DB

```
con = cx_Oracle.Connection('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cx_oracle equivalent to sqlplus / would be this:

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect('/')
```

If you want to connect through a tnsname like ORCL you need to set this parameter:

```
 alter system set remote_os_authent=TRUE scope=spfile;
```

Then your connection string will work. For me it was:

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect('','','ORCL')
```

In sqlplus the equivalent is

```
sqlplus /@ORCL
```

You can't do OS authentication over the network if you don't set remote_os_authent=TRUE. If you just use / you aren't going over the network. You have to bounce the database after changing the parameter.

Bobby

Comment: Hi Bobby, thanks for your comment.  I've dug a bit deeper, and discovered that although that parameter is set to FALSE on my DB, it is actually a deprecated parameter (my database being at version 11), hence the oracle connection from python should not be considering it when determining whether a connection is allowed or not - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams199.htm#

Comment: A deprecated parameter is just one that will be removed in a future release. The parameter works in version 11. I tested on 11.2.0.3 on Linux. But, it looks like you found the solution. Really, it isn't safe to use that parameter anyway so I don't advise it.